# curr.execute("""INSERT INTO CITY (name) values (%s);""",(cities)) fails to insert list into db

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to insert a list into a postgres table.

Inside the try, it fails on this line:

```
curr.execute("""INSERT INTO CITY (name) values (%s);""",(cities))
```

I've tried many variations including using just a string, or brackets and nothing is working. I've also tried executemany and that also doesn't work.

```
try:
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=testapp user=postgres")
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute("""INSERT INTO CITY (name) values (%s);""",(cities))
conn.commit()
curr.close()
conn.close()
```

except:
    print ("unable to insert")

EDIT:

I get "not all arguments converted during string formatting" with execute or executemany.

I created a smaller city list using

cities = ['San Francsico', 'San Jose']

But the actual list has 100 cities in it.

If I use

```
curr.executemany("INSERT INTO CITY (name) values (%s);","San Francisco",)
```

Then S 
a
n
etc
is inserted into the db, ie each row has a letter.

Comment: Can you show the contents of *cities*? And curious, can you show your `executemany` attempt? Same exception?

Comment: Remove the try/except - how does it actually fail? Post the traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, *you should be keeping your query parameters inside a tuple*:

```
city = "San Francisco"
curr.execute("""INSERT INTO CITY (name) values (%s);""", (city, ))
```

Note the comma after `city`.

---

In case of `executemany()`, you should have a *list of tuples*:

```
params = [("San Francisco", )]
curr.executemany("INSERT INTO CITY (name) values (%s);", params)
```

Or list of dictionaries, if you would have used *named parameters*:

```
params = [
    {"city": "San Francisco"}
]
curr.executemany("INSERT INTO CITY (name) values (%(city)s);", params)
```

---

If you want to adapt your `cities` list to `executemany()`, you can use:

```
params = [[city] for city in cities]
curr.executemany("INSERT INTO CITY (name) values (%s);", params)
```

---

<sub>Note: actually, when I say "tuples", I am not 100% correct - *iterables* would probably a better word - it's just that tuples are commonly used for the query parameters. I'll keep the answer as is for simplicity sake.</sub>

Comment: When I tried that it did do the insert but now all the cities are in one row  9 | {"San Francisco","New York",Washington,Milan,DC} But using instead executemany gives "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: @justcurious please see the updated answer. I've included a part where you can adapt `cities` to be used with `executemany()`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much and also for the good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

why using `"""`, change it to `"` ?

```
curr.execute("INSERT INTO CITY (name) VALUES (%s)", (cities))
```

and print exception get more detail:

```
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=testapp user=postgres")
    curr = conn.cursor()
    curr.execute("INSERT INTO CITY (name) VALUES (%s)", (cities))
    conn.commit()
    curr.close()
    conn.close()
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex) # print exception detail
```

**UPDATE**

you should using **bulk insert**, like:

```
INSERT INTO CITY (name) VALUES (%s),(%s),(%s)
```

Comment: I tried both single and three quotes based on something I saw online. I changed to the exception you mentioned and got this

Comment: I don't understand how the quoting change given is expected to help solve the problem (other than the improved exception handling, but since that's a diagnostic step as opposed to a fix, it's more appropriate for a comment).

Comment: I think answer is helpful because now I know what the issue is and before I didn't.

Comment: I agree that it's helpful. I don't agree that it's an *answer*. Not all helpful things are answers.

Comment: I saw bulk update before but I have 100 cities so I tried insert into city (name) values (%s), (%s), (%s), c for c in cities) and got SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

Comment: "bulk insert" with multi-valued `VALUES` list is horrid IMO. If you're going to do that, go straight to `COPY` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`executemany` needs a list of lists or tuples.

```
cities = [['San Francsico'],['San Jose']]
curr.executemany("INSERT INTO CITY (name) values (%s);",cities)
```